# remote desktop overtaking someone else's disconnected session

Tags: remote-desktop

We have one user account on the remote server. When computer A initiates a remote session, then disconnects from it, and computer B initiates a remote connection, computer B is being connected to the A's session.

How can I make sure that only the same device can reconnect to its remote session?

Comment: I'm wondering what exactly you're trying to achieve. I might be naive, but I don't understand the down-side of having a user be able to disconnect from one device and pick up the session from another. Your wording "someone else's...session" leads me to believe you have multiple people connecting to one user account?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. We have 25 clients and only one server. There is no need for them to have their own accounts so we just set up one local username on the server. The problem is that we would like them to actually be owners of their sessions, and not have other people be able to connect to "someone else's session."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a single user account I don't think you can. You need to make sure that they log off instead of disconnecting, then they can start a new session with the right account.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/62178/multiple-rdp-sessions-on-a-single-computer) for more info.

Comment: So even if I am sending an e-mail blast, and I disconnect from the session, there is no way other people can start new sessions without disturbing mine? :(

Comment: You may be able to, but you would have to configure mutliple sessions per user, I have added a link in my answer that might be helpful :)